# Workaround for the changed jdk6 to jdk7 behavior of substring

Tags: java, performance, substring

Up to jdk7u6 the substring method [was lightning fast](/q/16123446) because it simply used pointers within an existing string - thus required no memory copying. I used that feature extensively in implementing parsers.

Given the length of time since that critical performance feature was removed there must be some well oiled replacement.

Note: I could theoretically go back and copy the implementation from jdk6. But IIRC it was wrapped up pretty heavily in the entire String class - i.e. not easily extracted.

So is such an  implementation lying around - e.g in one of the high performance jvm parser libraries?

Comment: I'm just keep an external index, recording where we are at the string.

Comment: @bayou.io  That does not solve the need to extract and use the substring in a different method for example.

Comment: pass the index to that method too :D ... basically replace all `(String)` with `(String,int,int)`. (unless you can't do that with some other people's method)  it sucks of course...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to do what you need with CharBuffer, which implements the `CharSequence` interface. See, in particular, [`CharBuffer.subSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#subSequence(int,%20int)).

Comment: Looking at the impl for that now ..  CharBuffer is one of those nio guys. Long time back they were pretty heavyweight to instantiate (uncertain if that had changed..) After you have one then yes they would satisfy the requirements. So I will upvote but wait bit longer to see if a potentially lighter weight alternative exists.